# How do I access the created file when using File.WriteAllText() in an Elastic Beanstalk hosted application?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My web app is hosted in Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm trying to create a temporary text file, currently using `File.WriteAllBytes(path, "Some Text");`

Assuming I don't have access to the C:\ directory and anything in `path` would/should be relative to where the application is hosted on the filesystem.

Is anyone aware of what the `path` variable should be here? (I will be creating the file, uploading it to an S3 bucket, then deleting the file, so some code is not directly relevant to this question, I just wanted to give something...)

```
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccesKey, _awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
string filePath = @"C:\myTextfile.txt";
string folderPath = "textFiles/";

File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Some new text");
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
    BucketName = _bucketName,
    .............
```

Comment: To use a relative path (taking the root as the working directory) just use: `myTextFile.txt`. A better way would be `string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "myTextFile.txt");`

Comment: Please do not forget to clean up after posting the file to Amazon: `File.Delete(filePath);`